# generate output files with random samples from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sample

I have a dataframe with 500K rows. I need to distribute sets of 100 randomly selected rows to volunteers for labeling.

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,450,size=(450,1)),columns=list('a'))
```

I can remove a random sample of 100 rows and output a file with time stamp:

```
df_subset=df.sample(100)
df_subset.to_csv(time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') + 'dfsample.csv')
df=df.drop(df_subset.index)
```

the above works but if I try to apply it to the entire example dataframe:

```
while len(df)>0:
        df_subset=df.sample(100)
        df_subset.to_csv(time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') + 'dfsample.csv')
        df=df.drop(df_subset.index)
```

it runs continuously - my expected output is 5 timestampdfsample.csv files 4 of which have 100 rows and the fifth 50 rows all randomly selected from df however `df.drop(df_sample.index)` doesn't update df so condition is always true and it runs forever generating csv files. I'm having trouble solving this problem.

any guidance would be appreciated

*UPDATE*

this to gets me almost there:

```
for i in range(4):
        df_subset=df.sample(100)
        df=df.drop(df_subset.index)
        time.sleep(1) #added because runs too fast for unique naming
        df_subset.to_csv(time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') + 'dfsample.csv')
```

it requires me to specify number of files. If I say 5 for the example df I get an error on the 5th. I hoped for 5 files with the 5th having 50 rows but not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code, I think the problem is not with `df.drop`
but with the line containing `time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') + 'dfsample.csv'`, because Pandas creates multiple CSV files within a second which might be causing some overwriting issues.

I think if you want label files using a timestamp, perhaps going to the millisecond level might be more useful and prevent possibility of overwrite. In your case

```
while len(df)>0:
  df_subset=df.sample(100)
   
  df_subset.to_csv(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.%f") + 'dfsample.csv')
  df=df.drop(df_subset.index)
```

Comment: I kind of figured it out in the for loop but you're correct it did seem to be the problem (I was updating when you posted your answer). It still gives me the 4 files though with an error on the 5th. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That is because size of sample (100) is larger than population (50) in last iteration due to which we get `Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'` error. Since sampling with replacement might not be useful in your case, I think you should just make sure the population size is an integer multiple of sample size. So putting 500 instead of 450 would solve it in this example

Comment: yes sampling with replacement does not work for me. I wonder if I can have a variable sample size like if len(df)>=100: sample_size=100  else: sample_size=lend(df) and somehow pass sample_size in df.sample()

Comment: len(df)>=100: sample_size=100 else: sample_size=lend(df) in the loop works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to shuffle your rows and get rid of that awful loop.

```
df.sample(frac=1)
```

and save slices of the shuffled dataframe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. I am able to sample with df.sample(), save,  and remove sample from df but one output file at a time. To clarify the question I'd like the code to continue outputing files until all rows have been sampled.